# Manage state with huge memory usage - querying from storage

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Apologies if this sounds dumb! We are working with flink to make async IO calls. A lot of the times, the IO calls are repeated (same set of parameters) and about 80% of the APIs that we call return the same response for the same parameters. So, we would like to avoid making the calls again. We thought we could use state to store previous responses and use them again. The issue is that though our responses can be used again, the number of such responses is huge and therefore requires a lot of memory. Is there a way to persist this to drive and query as and when required?

Comment: You can use RocksDB as a state backend if you save the state in the form of a key value.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Using RocksDB with async i/o isn't straightforward, since you can only use rocksdb with keyed state, and the async i/o operator doesn't support keyed state. What do you have in mind?

Comment: @DavidAnderson What I thought was he can initially invoke a single lazy IO call and cache these results in a `MapState` which he can re-use later on when processing elements, thus he doesn't have to use the async IO operator.

Comment: @DavidAnderson , Thanks for the response. Let me know if this is possible. Can I use a non-keyed operator after async I/O to store the results of enrichments and then access them in an operator before the async i/o where I can simply set the results to the event so that the async i/o won't trigger the call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a dumb question at all!

A few facts reveal why this isn't straightforward:

1. Flink state is strictly local to a single operator. You can't access state in another operator.
2. Flink offers one state backend that can spill to disk, which is RocksDB. Only keyed state is stored in RocksDB -- non-keyed state always lives on the heap.
3. The async i/o operator can not be used on a keyed stream -- it only works in a non-keyed context.
4. Using Iterations (cyclic connections in the job graph) with the DataStream API is a very bad idea (because it breaks checkpointing).

Of course, it may not be necessary for the cache be in Flink's managed state.

Some options:

- Don't use keyed state for the cache. You could use something like a separate RocksDB instance for the cache, and implement the caching directly in the async i/o operator. If the cache would fit in memory, I'd suggest Guava.
- Don't use async i/o. Do the fetching and caching yourself in a ProcessFunction, as proposed by @YuvalItzchakov.
- You could use [Stateful Functions](https://statefun.io) instead. This is a new library and API that sits on top of Flink and overcomes some of the limitations listed above.
- You could build something like the diagram below. Here the cache is held in keyed state in a CoProcessFunction. If the cache misses, a downstream async i/o operator is used to fetch the missing data. This then has to be looped back to the cache using an external queue, such as Kafka, or Kinesis, or Pulsar.

```
                    +---------------------+                                       +------+
                    |                     +--results from cache+---------------^--> SINK |
+--requests+------> |  CoProcessFunction  |                                    |  +------+
                    |                     |                                    |
+--cache misses+--> |  cache in RocksDB   |                    +-----------+   |
                    |                     +--side output:      | fetch via +---+-> loop back
     SOURCES        +---------------------+  cache misses+---> | async i/o |       as 2nd input
                                                               +-----------+       to fill cache
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the detailed answer. We will evaluate the options and keep the thread updated.

Comment: Here are our limitations: 1. Our events have almost nothing in common other than the API calls that they might share. So keying them is not an option. 2. The API calls occupy about 90% of the logic implementation of the application and hence cannot get rid of Async IO. Assuming we would have to stick with Flink, only option 1 is left and we expect our cache size to be big so we would have to explore RocksDB / Redis. What would you suggest?

Comment: You can always key the events by adding a field that holds a random ID. (But do NOT do `keyBy(random.nextLong())`; the result of keyBy for each event must be deterministic.) Besides, you must have some basis for producing a key for each event, otherwise how can you implement caching?

Comment: we were thinking of using the hash of our API parameters for caching the response.

Comment: Makes sense. So use that as the key, if you decide you want one.